# Вывод вложенных списков из БД с помощью PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить следующую задачу.
Есть таблица Категории товаров. У них есть уровни от 0 до 6. Нужно вывести на страницу списки.Например, Имя1_категории_0: вней Имя1_категории_1: Имя1_категории_2 и т.д.Затем под соответствующими уровнями Имя2_категории_1 со своей вложенностью и т.д.

Comment: Что пробовали и что не получилось? Покажите код

Comment: Что только не пробовала, честно говоря. Но ничего не работало. Сейчас не покажу, так как за другим компом. Надо было мне подробнее описать. 
В таблице есть у каждой категории свой id и id предка кроме уровня. Пробовала сначала собрать все 0 уровня, взять их id и вытащить их потомков первого уровня, по родительскому id. Это получается, но массив большой вложенности получается и шаблон не хочет видеть его данные. Или я неправильно передаю. К слову, шаблоны отдельно, php отдельно, не в одном файле.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужна реккурсия. Почитайте, вот например ваш вопрос решен: http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread1232301.html